# Interpretation of sample rate

Tags: sampling, resampling

I'm a little confused about the sample rate:

If I have an audio file that was recorded with a sample rate of 48kHz, this means that there are 48,000 values per second in this file, right?

So when I read this file with a smaller sample rate of lets say 44.1 kHz I am summarizing every 44,100 values to one second so effectively I make the audio slower and thus longer than it actually is. Am I getting this correctly or do I have a total misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is correct-- if you sampled the audio recording at 48 KHz and then played those same samples back at 44.1 KHz you would be "time-stretching" the recording and it would be slower. However you can also resample the samples by the ratio of 147/160 to then have the 44.1KHz samples play back at the same speed.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. And  You are basically interpolating the sampled signal at a slower rate. A frequency domain picture is that when you sampled at $48khz$, and assuming the maximum frequency component in the audio signal was no more than 2$4Khz$, then this $24khz$ component will get mapped to digital frequency $\omega = \pi$.

But when you play it back at sampling rate $44.1Khz$, then $\omega = \pi$ will get mapped back to frequency $22.05Khz$. This will result in high frequency tones sounding like low frequency one. A simple example will be that a high pitched woman's voice sounding like a low pitched male voice.

I always prefer this f-domain picture over t-domain picture.

[image: interpolateAtLowerrate]

Answer (score 0):

You are right. If you play back your original samples at a lower sampling rate, the resulting signal will sound at a lower pitch, and will take longer to play.

If you want to convert your original samples to a lower sampling rate (but keeping pitch and length, and losing a bit of bandwidth), you need to *resample* your signal.

Most audio software, tools and libraries support resampling (to higher or lower rate).

You can read about the process (e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample-rate_conversion)), but it generally consists of a combination of digital low-pass filtering, compression and expansion blocks.